# Passing client IP information to Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I want to pass the ip of the client that initiated the build to the Jenkins job so I can access that information inside a class that extends "Builder" or as an environment variable, or anything that works.

So for example, in the console log of every build, I can print something like: "Job started by user1 from ip: 10.101.101.1"

I know I can get an audit trial by using the "Audit Trial" plugin for Jenkins, but I would like to print that information to the build console so it'll be more straight forward.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I want the ip of the user/client that started the job/build, which is not necessarily the ip of the jenkins slave the job is running on.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins  not able to pass the client IP to a variable at the moment , the Client IP you saw at the output log is remote cause message.

I would say it is indeed useful to get remote IP in a job to enable some callback functions . Alternatively you can pass the IP as parameter when make the remote call

1. echo $ipaddr in your shell script of jenkins job
2. Enable the string parameters in jenkins job
   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build
3. Make the call

   > curl -k -u user:apitoken -X POST
   >   https://jenkins.local/job/yourjob/build \   --data token=jobtoken \
   >   --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"ipaddr", "value":"x.x.x.x"}]}'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and use the "Prepare an environment for the run" option.

In the "Evaluated Groovy script" section, copy this code:

```
return [IP_ADDRESS: InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName]
```

Then, you use the $IP_ADDRESS in your build step section.

```
echo $IP_ADDRESS
```

Build log:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Evaluation the following Groovy script content: 
return [IP_ADDRESS: InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName]

[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test Groovy IP address/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6447343457570437614.sh
+ echo 172.16.203.72
172.16.203.72
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Sorry, I should probably worded better, I want the ip of the client/user that started the job, not the Jenkins server that the job is running on

Comment: Ho OK, it's another challenge :)