# Jenkins: Pass variable in JS file

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, monitoring, grafana

Hey I'm trying to pass some information in to a JS file.
The case:

My goal is it, to build Dashboards with Grafana, over scripted dashboards.
The script works fine and now I want to add a hostname to the script.
The hostname should be hardcoded in the file after the buildjob.

PS: I'm new in Jenkins and JS, so I'm open for all your ideas!

Have a nice day !

PPS: Tomorow is Weekend!<3

Comment: Lot of ways to do this, you can set a global variable (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) which i think it's the best way, or you can roughly grep the xml build file in the filesystem and getting the value you are looking for.. Can this help?

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy I actually can do this over the URL to. ( Script can fetch the hostname over the URL). I want to create several js file for each server.

So when i create a xml I have to configger the xml every time when I build a new dashboard, and I have to touch every script to say wich name it should grep..

Comment: So your Jenkins job is already able to get the information from the url? In these case both the way are suitable, you can inject it as env var and read it from js scripts, or you can call a sub job that will get the value from the prvious job an inject anywhere you want... am I understanding right?

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy hm no, It is an other way to do this. 
Grafana scripted Dashboard work like this: 
- write a script wich can be used for many servers.
-u can add a hostname in de URL like this grafanaurl.com/script.js/hostname=""
- but I want it that way that :
- A jenkins job, where I can pass a Hostname
- The hostname should be hardcoded in the file
- So every server get his own JS file

Comment: Can i ask what is exactly the flow of the Jenkins job? Honestly i'm not understanding :(  I don't know Grafana, but usually these kind of operations are all resolved in similar ways in Jenkins

Comment: Sure. The Job is simply:
1. Add the hostname in the file
2. save the file in the dashbaord directory so u can access it over the URL

Comment: Thanks. Is the hostname a parameter of the job? where is the job running in all the hostnames? where can i get the hostname information?

Comment: I just want to add the Hostname, when I go into the job itself and add it there.. :D

Comment: Okay! :D   so.... why can't you just the hostname as string parameter, set it as environment var with the plugin suggested and simply call the env var from the JS?

Comment: I'll try it and give you feedback! Thanks ! <3

Comment: Okay let me know! :D

Comment: Good Morning @ivoruJavaBoy!
I break my head over the weekend and I didn't figguerd out how this could work :D. Last but not least I would have to write a java program, which can combine the script with the hostname. 

But thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry it did not help :( honestly i use to figure out these kind of tricks with Jenkins, so if you have any further issue, try to ask, i may be able to help you... Hope you'll find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to get the value with Jenkins? e.g. (as parameters or getting it directly from the filesystem) once done you can inject it in a environment variable and use in any kind of script:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

I'm not sure about the flow of the job, but you can also create a post build script that look for the TRIGGERED JOB on the filesystem

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

The above plugin is very useful as it sets some Jenkins variable very useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140130/passing-client-ip-information-to-jenkins-job

Comment: I want to pass the "hostname" in the Jenkins Job..
The Variable should initialize the "hostname-variable" in the js file.. 
I know.. its a tricky question..